# How to filter district's list based on state selection using Angular material

Tags: typescript, angular-material

I need to filter districts based on the user's state selection.

So based on User's state selection i need to bind its corresponding districts to my district dropdown

I am using angular materials for UI

I tried this, but this is not working

**.html**

**STATE control**

```
     <mat-select placeholder="State" formControlName="states" [(ngModel)]="selectedState"  (ngModelChange)="getDistricts()">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let state of formInputs.states" [value]="state.stateId">
              {{ state.stateName }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
```

**DISTRICT control**

```
     <mat-select placeholder="District" formControlName="districts">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let district of formInputs.districts" [value]="district.districtId">
              {{ district.districtName }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
```

**.ts**

```
  selectedState: string;//It will have my selected state value on change event

   ...


getDistricts() {

try {
     var list = this.formInputs.districts;//It contains my entire district list
     var districts = this.filterDistricts(list);
    if (districts) {
       this.formInputs.districts = districts;
    }
    } catch (error) {

   }
}

 filterDistricts(data) {
  return data.filter(this.isBigEnough);
  }

  isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
             return (element == this.selectedState);
   }
```

My response array looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question is updating my .ts file. I modified my .ts's getDistricts() as follows

```
getDistricts() {
   try {
 
  var list = this.formInputs.districts;

  if (list) { 
    var districtsFilterd = list.filter((unit) => unit.stateId == this.selectedState);

    if (districtsFilterd) {
      this.formInputs.districts = districtsFilterd;
    }
  } 
}
catch (error) {
  debugger;
}
 }
```

Now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to listen to when the value of the state input changes:

```
   this.form.get('states').valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
      // assign the updated values to the district list here
    });
```

But that requires that your reactive form is setup correctly:

```
let form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
          states: new FormControl(),
          districts: new FormControl()
});
```

The assignment of the formControlName attribute in the html (which you did) now connects the form with the current values "automagically", so that you can always retrieve the current values from the form controls or the formGroup and also listen to their changes as described above. The ngModel (which you have, too) should not be necessary anymore.

The possible values for the dropdown should be kept in separate variables, apart from the form:

```
let states = ['state a', 'state b'];
let districts = ['district a', 'district b'];
```

Comment: In my .ts file on top i declared it as this  districts: [null, Validators.required],
    states: [null, Validators.required], for userForm = this.fb.group({. So is that enough?

Comment: Also with my above coding now the values are filtering properly by adding this  var districts = list.filter((unit) => unit.stateId = this.selectedState//my selected state); So do we really need this this.form.get('states').valueChanges.subscribe(v => { in this case?

Comment: Now my problem is filtered district value is not binding back to district dropdown